# Is it possible to read a users group membership in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft graph api to log users into an webapp using their domain email.

I am able to read a users basic profile by using

```
$token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$response = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")->setReturnType(Model\User::class)->execute();
var_dump($response);
```

Is there a way that I can read their groups? Or a way I can instruct the domain admin to pass this information to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [memberOf](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) method: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf`.

Note that you'll need one of the following [permission scopes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/permission_scopes) added to your initial token request.

- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Regardless of which of these scopes you choose, they all will require administrative consent before a regular user can authorize them. To do this,  you'll first need to have them go through the “Admin Consent” workflow. This workflow requires an administrator but once complete any users of your application will have “admin consent” to the restricted scope.

For example, you would normally you would then authenticate users by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?<your params>`.

Since this scope requires an Admin however,  you fist need to obtain consent by first having an Admin authenticate by redirecting them to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?<yours params>`.

Once an Admin grants consent, normal users will be able to use OAUTH to authenticate.